# select sum where sum

Tags: mysql, sum, max

I want to select some entries based on a max+sum condition.

```
mytable
----------
id | col1 | col2
```

I want to select all entries that have  the sum of col1 & col2 greater than or equal to the max of sum minus X. (don't ask me why :) )

So far I managed to get the sum OK (hereafter aliased as "total") with:

```
SELECT id,SUM(col1 + col2) AS total FROM mytable GROUP BY id;
```

I also managed to get the MAX of the sum OK (with a ORDER BY/LIMIT workaround though):

```
SELECT id,SUM(col + col) as total FROM mytable GROUP BY id ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 1;
```

However everytime I try to re-use my alias as a condition (e.g. WHERE total >= ...) I get an **"Unknown column" error**

Anything would be greatly appreciated

Comment: For others with similar issues, `WHERE` clauses are evaluated before the expressions in your selection, in order to determine which rows it should even bother looking at. `HAVING` is like a `WHERE` after the fact, so although it can be slower, it's useful if what you're selecting is the same thing you're evaluating. In this case you would just use `HAVING total >= x`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have some misconceptions about `SUM`. `SUM` is an aggregating function, means it works on many records and not just one.
To calculate the sum of two fields per record, you should use only the `+` operator.

```
SELECT id, col1+col2 AS 'total'
FROM T1
WHERE
(col1+col2+x) >=(SELECT MAX(col1+col2) from T1)
```

Comment: indeed I misunderstood the SUM function. col+col1 does work for the total however I'm still getting that "Unknown column 'total' in 'where clause" error. I've tried changing total to test (in case the word was reserved, I have tried different syntaxes, I also simplified the where clause by putting a fixed value after >=, nothing, I just can't get it to work. How could I help you help me here?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using group by, you'll need to use a having clause:

```
SELECT id,SUM(col1+col2) as total FROM mytable GROUP BY id ORDER BY total HAVING total >= x
```

Comment: -1 the condition is the MAX of the two fields summary minus X, not just X. and why are you using SUM?! and how would you get the MAX of the entire table with a group by? You must use an inner query!